# Wrong version of image from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a problem with the UIImagePickerController component. Currently in my app the user can pick an image from the saved photos library with the picker, no problems there.

However, it seems that if I crop and save a photo *in Photos.app* before picking the image, UIImagePickerController gives me the original uncropped version in the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` dictionary key.

I understand that `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` works when the crop is done inside the picker, but when done in the Photos app this key returns nil.

So my question is, how do I access the correct version of the image (without rolling my own picker with ALAssetLibrary)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple; I was using `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum` instead of `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`.

Answer (score 0):

What is your

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)pickr didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo;
```

method like?

Have you tried to do something like

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)pickr didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [myImageView setImage:image];
    [pickr dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

(in the example it's `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`, don't know if you set YES to your picker `allowEditing`)

Comment: Yup, that's basically it - `allowEditing` is set to `NO` so `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` returns nil; `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` gives me the version of the image that was first saved to the device, not the version edited in Photos.app.

Comment: Try to set allowEditing to YES, I think that the version edited into Photos.app may be recognized as "edited", then it gives you back the original one